# Formula to offset a value in excel to a different column?

Tags: excel, random, offset

I am trying to create a formula that offsets an "up-sell" amount 12 periods (columns) in the future.

For background: Each of our customers provides monthly recurring revenue (like a subscription. At the beginning of the model (1/1/18), I have a random number generator from 1-20 that calculates the period in which the customer could be up-sold.
As you can see in the photo and the formula that the IF statement looks at the random upsell period and adds in the additional revenue ($100) into that period and periods after that.

I am trying to create the formula so that once the if statement is satisfied (the random period >= the period that the cell is in) it adds the revenue 12 periods *later*, not in that period itself. 
For example, Customer ABC's random upsell period is 3, instead of adding that revenue in period 3, I want it to add it in period 15 (12 periods later).

The formula that is currently being used is: `=IF($B8>E$5,$C8,$C8+$D$3)`

Please see attached image for reference, thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yk1d.png)

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you are looking for and only works if your periods increments in 1 even after 12++ (13,14,15...).
Sorry you'll have to redefine the references but that gives you an idea:

In C5 : `IF(C$4>12,IF(OFFSET(C4,0,-12)>=$A5,$C$2+$B5,$B5),$B5)`

[image]

Comment: Works great and exactly what I was looking for, thank you!